# jQuery this doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a problem with my jquery code:

```
<ul class="category-titles">
    <li><a id="category-title" href="">Test</a>
    </li>
    <li><a id="category-title" href="">Test 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a id="category-title" href="">Test 3</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="toolbar">
    <h1 id="results-title">Test</h1>
</div>

$('.category-titles > li > a').mouseover(function() {
    var strTitle = $('.category-titles > li > a', this).text();
    $("#results-title").html(strTitle);
    console.log(strTitle);
});
```

here is a link: http://jsfiddle.net/irider89/Ltd1fp79/6/ 
On mouse enter the title should be renamed as li titles.

Comment: All the answers below will work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are binding event to anchor so `this` refers to anchor element. So simply use

```
var strTitle = $(this).text();
```

instead of

```
var strTitle = $('.category-titles > li > a',this).text();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/b3pyzx57/)

Important: **IDs are unique identifier**

Answer (score 1):

If you capture the `mouseover` event over `.category-titles > li > a` elements, then `this` refers to these selected elements. Just use `$(this).text()` to get the text of hovered element.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Ltd1fp79/7/

Answer (score 1):

Just reference the `$(this)`, instead of:

```
$('.category-titles > li > a').mouseover(function(){
    var strTitle = $('.category-titles > li > a',this).text();
    $("#results-title").html(strTitle);
    console.log(strTitle);
});
```

Use this:

```
$('.category-titles > li > a').mouseover(function(){
    var strTitle = $(this).text();
    $("#results-title").html(strTitle);
    console.log(strTitle);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
var strTitle = $('.category-titles > li > a',this).text();
```

to this:

```
var strTitle = $(this).text();
```

Since your event is already bound to `'.category-titles > li > a'`, `this` refers to the link that fired the event.